# ubuntu 18 install using ks.cfg over http

Tags: 18.04, server, system-installation, preseed

I have downloaded ubuntu 18.04 Server install image (iso),
and created ks.cfg file with all the settings for the server - like ip, subnet, gw, hostname ,etc..
I need help to edit the iso image file to point the installer the location of the ks.cfg file over *http* (network).

> my kick-start (ubuntu18.cfg) file looks like this:
>
> #Generated by Kickstart Configurator
> #platform=x86
> #System language lang en_US
> #Language modules to install langsupport en_US
> #System keyboard keyboard us
> #System mouse mouse
> #System timezone timezone America/New_York
> #Root password rootpw --disabled
> #Initial user user me --fullname "" --password XXXXXX!
> #Reboot after installation reboot
> #Use text mode install text
> #Install OS instead of upgrade install
> #Use Web installation url --url http://172.16.60.175/ubuntu.iso
> #System bootloader configuration bootloader --location=mbr
> #Clear the Master Boot Record zerombr yes
> #Partition clearing information clearpart --all --initlabel
> #System authorization infomation auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5
> #Network information network --bootproto=static --ip={{ipaddr}} --netmask={{subn}} --gateway={{gw}} --nameserver=8.8.8.8 --device=eth0 --hostname={{hostn}}
> #Firewall configuration firewall --disabled

i didn't change nay file inside the iso file,
i need help to understand what file i need to change in the iso file and how to rebuild it back:)
all the lines with {{ver}} it is variable coming from script to create the kikstart file -thanks you!

Comment: Welcome! I assume we're dealing with ubuntu server 18.04 automated install using preseed. Notice you don't have to use the exact file name "ks.cfg", and if using preseed files. can you please provide us your preseed file? Did you edit any other files? Have you followed any online manuals / guides ? Please edit the question so we can understand your problem better.

Comment: hello, can you please help me? i have try a lot of things but i am missing something